# Patterns not Matching with Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a SOA Service in eclipse. And there is one field in which I have to insert Admin Name. So whenever I am entering this as an Admin Name and I am getting this error-

**Invalid Name. The name [Adcommerce, pubcommerceHelloWorldServiceV1] is not valid against the pattern "[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*"**

I am entering this as an Admin Name-

```
Adcommerce, pubcommerceHelloWorldServiceV1
```

Anything wrong I am entering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name has to start with a letter, and after that it can be multiple letters, digits and/or underscores, for example `random_123`.

It cannot contain the comma and space you use there, perhaps you'd best replace it with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a comma in your string but not your regexp.

Maybe something like so, if you can have more that one comma:,

```
"[A-Za-z]+[A-Zaf-z0-9_,]*"
```

or
    "[A-Za-z],+[A-Za-z0-9_,]*"

if the comma is always after the first "word"